# How will this asynchronous code execute in Python vs. C?

Tags: python, c, asynchronous

Let's say I have a simple script with two functions below. As callback_func is invoked I would assume it will only run in a singular basis. That i, there won't be two events passing through the code block at the same time. Is that correct? Also, if the callback_func is run in a singular basis, the messaging service itself would have to perform some buffering so no messages are lost, and that buffering is depending on the service originating the event. Is that also correct?

```
def callback_func(event):
    # Can be called anytime

def main_func():
    # Sets up a connection to a messaging service
```

Then what if I add a send_func? If I receive one message but I have three going out, how will `send_func` deal with a situation when it gets called while sending a message? Is such a situation handled by the Python interpreter?

```
def send_func(event):
    # Can be called anytime

def callback_func(event):
    # Can be called anytime

def main_func():
    # Sets up a connection to a messaging service
```

Then lastly, if I change the language to C, how do the answers to my questions above change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Confusing Two Concepts ( Asynchronous != Concurrent )

**Asynchronous** does not imply **Concurrent**, and **Concurrent** does not imply **Asynchronous**. These terms get semantically confused by beginners ( and some experts ), but they are different concepts!

You can have one without the other, or both sometimes.

Asynchronous means you don't wait for something, it doesn't imply that it happens while other things do, just that it may happen later..

**Concurrent** means more than one completely individual thing is happening at the exact same time, these things can be Synchronous while being isolated and concurrent.

#### Implementation Specific

[CPython](http://python.org/) is single threaded, there is no concern about re-entry. [Other Python runtimes](http://pypy.org/) allow for concurrency and would need locking mechanisms if those features were used.

C is inherently single threaded as well unless you are specifically starting new threads, then you would need a locking mechanism.

Comment: Example of something that is not concurrent but is asynchronous: [node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that there are many places that message buffering can happen other than the "service".  At a low level, I believe the operating system will buffer incoming and outgoing bytes on a socket.